# Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined

Tags: file-upload, xml-parsing, p5.js

I have an XML file with 4000 childs.  Within each are several children entries. Using P5.js. I use loadXML to load the file, then when completed, I run this code, checking first to see if there is an xmlWx.

```
    airportData = xmlWx.getChild('data').getChildren('METAR');
    stations = xmlWx.getChild('data').getChildren('station_id');
    latitudes = xmlWx.getChild('data').getChildren('latitude');
    longitudes = xmlWx.getChild('data').getChildren('longitude');
```

I intermittently get

```
Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined
```

Here is a data example:

```
<METAR>
<raw_text>KIFP 091948Z 22004KT 10SM BKN080 BKN100 18/M04 A2994</raw_text>
<station_id>KIFP</station_id>
<observation_time>2021-02-09T19:48:00Z</observation_time>
<latitude>35.15</latitude>
<longitude>-114.57</longitude>
</METAR>
```

With 4000 entries, its possible that there are missing entries.  But It goes away if I keep restarting the code.  Is there away to check for this because it seems to stop the processing when encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all children were present in each child.